# pivot chart "For Each" function

Tags: vba, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am trying to make a pivot chart change its axis subject based on a dropdown value in a cell. I have been able to get this work when changing the data fields (values) using the following code.

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PF As PivotField
Dim sField As String

        For Each PF In PT.DataFields
        
          If PF.Name <> sField Then
          
            PF.Orientation = xlHidden
            
          End If
          
        Next PF
```

However, when I try to do the same for the axis of the pivot chart I get a run time error (424 - object required) using the following code. I believe that the issue lies in the "PivotTable.PivotAxis" line and has something to do with the .PivotAxis.

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PF As PivotField
Dim sField As String
Dim PA As PivotAxis

        For Each PA In PT.PivotAxis
        
          If PA.Name <> sField Then
          
            PA.Orientation = xlHidden
            
          End If

    Next PA
```

Does anyone have any solutions as to how I can check each pivot axis name in a pivot chart iteratively?

Comment: I don't believe a pivot table has a `PivotAxis` property.

Comment: there is a PivotRowAxis property but I tried that and that did not work either, is there somewhere I could check the list of properties?

Comment: F2 to bring up the Object Browser. Or record a macro and inspect the recorded code - might give you some hints as to what you're looking for.